# ¿Como guardar elementos de una estructura de datos circular doble enlace en una list view, cuando se le agregan elemento desde Jfilechooser?

Tags: java, javafx, listview, scenebuilder, jfilechooser

//AQUI SE CREA EL ID DE LISTVIEW QUE ES CANCIONES

```
@FXML private ListView<ListaCircularD2enlazada> canciones;

//ESTE ES EL ID DE LABEL DONDE SI SE MUESTRA LA CANCION SELECCIONADA Y GUARDADA 

@FXML private  Label textoCancion;
```

//SIENDO honesto no se como crearlo ni instanciarlo lo he intentado pero no lo logro, miLista es una instaccia de una clase ya creada con una estructura de datos, estoy creando un reproductor mp3.

```
ListView<ListaCircularD2enlazada> listaCanciones  = new ListView<ListaCircularD2enlazada>();

ObservableList <ListaCircularD2enlazada> items = FXCollections.observableList();

public void agregarAction(MouseEvent event) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivo MP3", "mp3", "mp3"));
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    int selection = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (selection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File files[] = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        boolean noMp3 = true, repetidos = false;

        for (File file : files) {
            //AQUI SE ESTA INSERTANDO ELEMENTOS A LA LISTA
            miLista.insertarCacion(file.getName(),file.getPath());
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
            //AQUI SE MUESTRA EL ELEMENTO RECIEN AÑADIDO EN UNA LABEL CON ID textoCancion
            textoCancion.setText(file.getName());
            //AQUI DEBERIA ESTAR LA LINEA EN LA QUE MUESTRE LOS ELEMENTOS QUE SE SELECCIONAS Y SE GUARDAN EN 
            //LA ESTRUCTURA y DEBERIAN APARECER EN LA LISTVIEW
            listaCanciones

        }
        if (!noMp3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es un archivo mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Permíteme hacerte algunos comentarios sobre esta pregunta.

A mi me parece que deberías ser más preciso en tu pregunta. Y sobre todo, limpiar el código que muestras.

Por legibilidad, procura no usar jamás variables booleanas cuyo nombre empiece por "no". Aunque por lo que parece, la variable noMp3 no sirve de nada y por tanto también forma parte de lo que deberías eliminar. Creo que es por tu propio interés, si deseas que se te responda de forma eficaz, formula la pregunta de forma concisa.

Parece que la variable "canciones" es la que en el cuerpo de la función se llama "miLista". Eso también deberías corregirlo.

A la función insertarCacion(), mejor llámala insertarCancion(), que luego llegará un dia que la buscarás y no la encontraràs. Y por amor al código. Debes amar tu código, creo.

A esa función le pasas dos parámetros que salen de un mismo objeto. Eso no tiene mucho sentido. Mejor pasale el objeto, que igual que los separas en la llamada, también los sabrá separar el cuerpo de la función. No tiene sentido poner esos dos parámetros.

Y una última cosa, donde pone "//AQUI DEBERIA ESTAR LA LINEA EN LA QUE MUESTRE LOS ELEMENTOS QUE SE SELECCION...", eso no es así. Si deseas imprimir por pantalla el contenido completo de la lista, tiene que ser fuera de ese bucle, o sea, en un bucle posterior. Tal como lo tienes ahora, en ese lugar solo puedes imprimir el nombre de un fichero, el actual, no la lista completa.